# VPN help for Android

Tags: networking, vpn, android, ip

I have an Android application that talks to a server app running on grails (Groovy on Grails).

Android app basically establishes a connection with this address:

```
url="http://192.168.2.53:8080/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop";
```

It all works fine when both the server and the Android phone are connected in the same LAN network.

Now the problem arises when I want the phone to talk to the server while the phone is outside the local network (I need it to use edge).

I came across VPN networks which I think might help me out. (the server has dynamic IP)

So what I did was go to dyndns.com and created a new hostname and have the app successfully run on the server. The host I created was - tmagrails.dyndns.com

How do I make my phone connect to this network? What changes am I supposed to make in order to get things working? Also, I really want to know if this is the right approach. If not, is there any way to get things going for me?

Answer (score 2):

Forget VPN! If your router has the feature (most of them do), you can enable **port forwarding**, so for example you could forward the external port 80 to the internal port 8080 of your server:

```
external port 80 -> 192.168.2.53:8080
```

That way you can reach your test server from the outside without the need for VPN (which is kind of complicated to set up). The benefit is that most ISPs don't block port 80.

If you already have DynDNS, then after enabling port forwarding you only need to go to:

```
http://tmagrails.dyndns.com/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop
```

Comment: I don't know how to forward that port. Is there any procedure for it? I'm currently using a UTStarcom modem Model: UT300R2T  (It isn't listed in portforward.com)

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. I don't know that brand/model. Can you connect to the modem by entering its IP address into the browser?

Comment: yes i can do that. By going to 192.168.1.1, i'm able to get to my router page

Comment: Awesome, if you have port forwarding options, they're somewhere there. Good luck.

Comment: No.. I don't see any port forwarding options there. Although, i have a NAT - DMZ host address option. Would that be of any use?

Comment: I really can't tell. This is very specific, maybe you should open another question for exactly that problem (with your Router/Modem model and what you want to do)

Comment: alright. THanks!  I did a quick port check using a torrent client. It seems that this port a particular port is open. (not sure if its safe tp post the port number)  Would it be of any use?