# Enable Port Forwarding on UTStarcom UT300R2T

Tags: port-forwarding, hostname, dynamic-dns

This question is a reference to [VPN help for Android](https://superuser.com/questions/278409/vpn-help-for-android)

I want to visit this page on my server

```
http://192.168.2.53:8080/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop
```

Since it's a dynamic IP, the above mentioned IP address keeps changing everytime I reset my connection. I replaced the IP with a DynDNS hostname I created

```
http://tmagrails.dyndns-ip.com/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop
```

However, I'm unable to access this page from a remote machine (any machine outside the server's network)

I was asked to forward the port 80 to 8080. I'm unable to do so as there is **no port forwarding option in my router page.** I use a UTStarcom UT300R2T modem/router.

Is there any workaround for this?